# How to use if else statement to create attribute in shapefile using R

Tags: shapefile, r, if-else

I am working on a if statement within R to populate a new variable called `d1` with values from my income field if variable A equals 1, otherwise autofill zeros. I'm having issues with getting it to work however (see error below).

```
[2025] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[2036] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[2047] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[2058] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[2069] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[2080] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
Warning messages:
1: In if (br10$decile == "1") { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used


if (myshapefile$varA== "1") {
myshapefile$d1 == myshapefile$income
} else if (myshapefile$varA != "1") {
myshapefile$d1 == "0"
}
```

Comment: There's nothing GIS related here, it looks like a standard R data frame.

Comment: I would recommend adding some sample data.

Answer (score 2):

This is not how you replace elements of a vector:

```
if (myshapefile$varA== "1") {
myshapefile$d1 == myshapefile$income
} else if (myshapefile$varA != "1") {
myshapefile$d1 == "0"
}
```

An `if` test has to evaluate to a *single* true or false value to decide which block of code to execute. You are trying to run it on a vector of your `varA` values.

I guess you really want an `ifelse`. Set up some test sample data:

```
> myshapefile = data.frame(varA=c("1","X","X","1"), income=1:4)
> myshapefile
  varA income
1    1      1
2    X      2
3    X      3
4    1      4
```

Now you want `d1` to be the `income` value where `varA` is `"1"` and `"0"` otherwise? Do this:

```
> myshapefile$d1 = ifelse(myshapefile$varA=="1", income, "0")
> myshapefile
  varA income d1
1    1      1  1
2    X      2  0
3    X      3  0
4    1      4  4
```